# Linear Regression Model output in R saying: "2 not defined because of singularities"

Tags: r, regression, least-squares

I am running a linear regression model in R where soya beans `yield` is predicted by soya varieties (`spike`,`maksoy`,`uyole` and `local`), type of fertilizer used (`DAP`,`NPK`,`unfertilized`) and use of `inoculant` for improved Nitrogen fixing.

The model runs but it lets me know that `Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)`. A little research tells me that this is due to multicollinearity.

Can anyone put this in laymans language in the context of my data? Below is a runnable version of my code.

```
soya_data = readr::read_csv(paste0(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datakilimba/S38---Soya-Demos/master/",
  "soya_demo_data.csv"))

soya_yield_model = lm(yield ~ spike+maksoy+uyole+local+DAP+NPK+unfertilized+ 
                        inoculant, data = soya_data)

summary(soya_yield_model)
```

Comment: This isn't multicollinearity: it is collinearity, pure and simple.  Two of your variables are perfect linear combinations of the remaining ones.  The output of `summary` has already answered your question by identifying two such variables.  When your software has a definite error message, it's always a good idea to [search for it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22not+defined+because+of+singularities%22+answers%3A1).  That shows you other cases where the same message appeared and the question has an answer.

Comment: You apparently dummy coded all levels for each of `variety` and `fertilizer_type` separately. When you have predictors like that, combine all levels into a single multi-level categorical predictor.